# How make my PHP code print to seperate divs?

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to but the prints from this php code into seperate html div's so I can customize them with css. I got a css file made and it shows but everything is printed out into one div called body class=" hasGoogleVoiceExt".

```
<?php
class Bot {
    public $botHost = '127.0.0.1';
    public $botPort = 8087;
    public $botId = NULL;
    public $token = NULL;
    public function __construct($botHost = '127.0.0.1', $botPort = 8087, $botId = NULL) {
        $this->botHost = $botHost;
        $this->botPort = $botPort;
        if ($botId == NULL) {
            $botId = $this->DefaultBot();
        }
        $this->botId = $botId;
    }
    public function DefaultBot() {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'http://'.$this->botHost.':'.$this->botPort.'/api/v1/botId',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
        ));
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $json = json_decode($data, TRUE);
        return $json['defaultBotId'];
    }
    public function Login($username, $password) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'http://'.$this->botHost.':'.$this->botPort.'/api/v1/bot/login',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'botId' => $this->botId)),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json')
        ));
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($code != 200) return NULL;
        $this->token = json_decode($data, TRUE)['token'];
    }
    public function GetInstances() {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'http://'.$this->botHost.':'.$this->botPort.'/api/v1/bot/instances',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Authorization: bearer '.$this->token)
        ));
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($code != 200) return NULL;
        $json = json_decode($data, TRUE);
        return $json;
    }
    public function GetInstanceStatus($instanceId) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'http://'.$this->botHost.':'.$this->botPort.'/api/v1/bot/i/'.$instanceId.'/status',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Authorization: bearer '.$this->token)
        ));
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($code != 200) return NULL;
        $json = json_decode($data, TRUE);
        return $json;
    }
}

$bot = new Bot('127.0.0.1', 8087);
$bot->Login('admin', 'foobar');
$instances = $bot->GetInstances();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($instances); $i++) {
    $info = $bot->GetInstanceStatus($instances[$i]['uuid']);
    if ($info['currentTrack'] != NULL && $info['playing']) {
        printf("%s is playing %s by %s\n", $instances[$i]['nick'], $info['currentTrack']['title'], $info['currentTrack']['artist']);
    } else {
        printf("%s is not playing anything right now\n", $instances[$i]['nick']);
    }
    echo '<link href="botcss/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
}
```

I'm currently testing it out here http://theunlighted.com/nowplaying.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: Your `<link [...]>` needs to be output before the `for()` loop.

Secondly, to output divs in a way (that I think you're meaning to do) is simple:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 123; $i++) {
  echo '<div class="foo foo_'.$i.'">';
  // do other output here.
  echo '</div>';  
}
```

Comment: Thank You I got in now, very helpful!

Comment: you should really use the id element for setting unique identifies  on divs instead of giving them unique class names.. kind of defeats the purpose of  classes making them unique... and you can use ids in css as discriminators to apply to specific elements

Comment: To each their own. Using CSS classes, you can target them using attribute selectors as well. Such as `.foo[class~="foo_3"]`, etc